# How do I add a socket.io socket to a room via their socketid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm running a function with this line I pilfered from the internet somewhere:

```
io.sockets[socketID].join(roomName);
```

It isn't working properly. Is there any way I can accomplish adding a socket to a room without having reference to the socket object? Or is there any way to get a reference to the socket object from an ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In socket.io 1+, you would use the socket id on the server like this:

```
io.sockets.connected[socketID].join(roomName);
```

Comment: For those that get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined` like I did just now, you need to make sure the socket is currently connected. You can wrap this in a statement like `if (Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).includes(
                          socketID) {//code here}`